# Objects in Javascript "Assign"

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object

```
var person1{
    name :  "John",
    lastName : "Doe"
}
```

And I did an assignment like this

```
person2 = person1;
```

But If I do this:

```
person1.name = "Mike";
```

Then person2.name is "Mike" 
What I'm trying is to make person2 "independent". 
What is going on? is like "referencing objects" ?

Comment: Assigning objects with/to variables is basically referencing them. Also you're missing a equal sign ^_^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exactly right. It is a referencing situation. There is no cloning going on when you assign an object to a variable, the program just creates a new reference to person1 called person2

You would have to use a dedicated cloning function, depending on if you are using pure JS or a framework like jQuery.

Here is a pure JS solution (source http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/):

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }

    var temp = obj.constructor(); // give temp the original obj's constructor
    for (var key in obj) {
        temp[key] = cloneObject(obj[key]);
    }

    return temp;
}
var person2 = cloneObject(person1);
```

Comment: Oh very interesting! thanks! I'm trying to understand that code :P !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the object is serializable to JSON, you could do:

```
person2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person1));
```

Comment: Nice! very simple and efficient!

Answer (score 1):

In that situation I do this:

```
// a function that returns a generic object
function newPerson(){
return {name:"",lastName:""};

}

//then, calling the function we get an independent object 
var person1=newPerson();
var person2=newPerson();
person1.name="Jon";
person2.name="Bob";
```

Comment: Yes, perhaps is not the 'standard' way, but it looks simpler , you can even add methods

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

`var p2 ={
    name : person1.name, 
    lastname : person1.lastName
}`

this way, it won't be referenced because you're passing simple types, not objects